# Creating a 2D array in IDL starting from an equation

Tags: arrays, contour, idl-programming-language

I'm trying to make a contour plot in IDL of quantity described by and equation, which here I'll take to be x^2 + y.
In order to do that, I first need to create a 2D array ("pxx").

Being a novice, I'm currently just moving my fist step into this direction and so far I've been trying to make this simpler foreach loop work:

```
pxx=fltarr(10, 10)

xx = indgen(10)
yy = indgen(10)

foreach k, xx do begin
  pxx[k,*]=3*k
endforeach
  
print, pxx
```

But this only seems to work for the last column. Any idea on how to fix that? And how would you suggest I proceed to create a 2D array in space for the equation above?
Thank you in advance, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Choose the range of `x` and `y` values you want to evaluate on:

```
n = 10
x = findgen(n) - (n - 1)/2.0
y = findgen(n) - (n - 1)/2.0
```

Expand `x` and `y` to 2-dimensional versions of themselves:

```
xx = rebin(reform(x, n, 1), n, n)
yy = rebin(reform(y, 1, n), n, n)
```

Evaluate the function:

```
z = xx^2 + yy
```

Plot:

```
contour, z, x, y
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this has been really helpful